# Sending data to spring controller using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I know that this question has been asked many times, but I have looked at every variation I could find and have still not been able to find out my issue.

Here is my ajax call:

```
function sendFormData(endpoint) {
    console.log("CLICKING BUTTON");

    var input = {
            "userInputOne": "hello1", 
            "userInputTwo": "hello2", 
            "userInputThree": "hello3", 
            "userInputFour": "hello4", 
            "userInputFive": "hello5"
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        url: endpoint,
        asynch: false,
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
        } 

    });

}
```

The endpoint works.  You can take my word for it.

Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        private @ResponseBody String getFormData(@RequestBody FormInput userInput, HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) {

        String userInput1 = userInput.getInputOne();
        String userInput2 =  userInput.getInputTwo();
        String userInput3 = userInput.getInputThree();;
        String userInput4 = userInput.getInputFour();
        String userInput5 = userInput.getInputFive();

        return "success";

    }
```

And here is my model class:

```
public class FormInput {
    private String userInputOne;
    private String userInputTwo;
    private String userInputThree;
    private String userInputFour;
    private String userInputFive;

    public FormInput(String userInputOne, String userInputTwo, String userInputThree, String userInputFour, String userInputFive) {
        this.userInputOne = userInputOne;
        this.userInputTwo = userInputTwo;
        this.userInputThree = userInputThree;
        this.userInputFour = userInputFour;
        this.userInputFive = userInputFive;
    }

    public String getUserInputOne() {
        return this.userInputOne;
    }

    public String getUserInputTwo() {
        return this.userInputTwo;
    }

    public String getUserInputThree() {
        return this.userInputThree;
    }

    public String getUserInputFour() {
        return this.userInputFour;
    }

    public String getUserInputFive() {
        return this.userInputFive;
    }

}
```

I keep getting a HTTP status code of 415, which means unsupported media type.  I set the contentType to "application/json", and I also tried to add "consumes= 'application/json'" to my Spring controller and that didn't help either.  Thank you for any help you can give.

**EDIT**: I am now getting the following error after changing RequestMethod.GET to RequestMethod.POST: "Error 405: Request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: try this `dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  `

Comment: Have you tried sending data as JSON object instead of string. `data: input`?

Comment: @pvpkiran Still no luck.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Yes I did try that.

Comment: Not sure but can you make controller method(getFormData) _public_ and try?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel Good idea, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error of: "Error 405: Request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: I think, ajax is trying for GET request though you mentioned as POST. Can you add screen shot of _Network_ tab of Chrome developer tool? If it showing POST request, it would be really great if you put your code into some public repository, so I can check.

Comment: Can you debug and see what the `endpoint` looks like in console? **NOTE:**  If the `url` is not dynamic, set the 'url' param in the ajax function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to send parameter as `json`,you have made things complicated

In javascript code,you can remove `contentType: "application/json",` and change the format of `data` property to send data directly

```
function sendFormData(endpoint) {
    console.log("CLICKING BUTTON");

    var input = {
            "userInputOne": "hello1", 
            "userInputTwo": "hello2", 
            "userInputThree": "hello3", 
            "userInputFour": "hello4", 
            "userInputFive": "hello5"
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        //contentType: "application/json",
        data: input,//send data directly
        url: endpoint,
        asynch: false,
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
        } 

    });

}
```

In java code,you can remove `@ResponseBody` annotation before `FormInput`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private @ResponseBody String getFormData(FormInput userInput, HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) {

        String userInput1 = userInput.getInputOne();
        String userInput2 =  userInput.getInputTwo();
        String userInput3 = userInput.getInputThree();;
        String userInput4 = userInput.getInputFour();
        String userInput5 = userInput.getInputFive();

        return "success";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The java controller method you have written is of type 'GET', it should be changed to 'POST', as the ajax call you are making is also of type POST
Try this and it will work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            private @ResponseBody String getFormData(@RequestBody FormInput userInput, HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model) {

            String userInput1 = userInput.getInputOne();
            String userInput2 =  userInput.getInputTwo();
            String userInput3 = userInput.getInputThree();;
            String userInput4 = userInput.getInputFour();
            String userInput5 = userInput.getInputFive();

            return "success";

        }
```

Comment: Getting the following error: "Error 405: Request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: just try changing type:"post" to type: "POST". and share the result and java controller method  to 'POST' as well

Comment: Edited my question to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess main problem in not match http methods. You sent by POST method, but controller wait for GET method.

Comment: I tried that initially but got the following error: "Error 405: Request method 'GET' not supported"

Comment: Rewtite in your controller: method = RequestMethod.POST

Answer (score 0):

This is because your method signature doesn't match. Just remove `contentType: "application/json"`.